# Reactive Spring Security is always creating the Session in redis even when NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository specified for securityContextRepository

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux, reactive

Reactive Spring Security is always creating the Session even when NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository specified for securityContextRepository

Tried below two methods and still Session object is being created in redis

**Method-1**

```
    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityWebFilterChain configure(ServerHttpSecurity http) throws Exception {     
        http.authorizeExchange().pathMatchers("/api/path")
                .authenticated()            
            .and()
                .securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance())
            .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
        return http.build();
    }
```

**Method-2**

```
@Bean
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public SecurityWebFilterChain configure(ServerHttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http
.requestCache().disable()
.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();

    return http.build();
}
```

By trying both of the above given methods still every time redis Session object is creating when I invoke my API /api/path.
Here is the github [project](https://github.com/svankamamidi/reactive-spring-redis-session/tree/main/websession) where issue can be reproduced,

1. invoke GET http://localhost:8080/api/websession?id=222&note=helloworld
2. Check the redis keys. Ideally no key should be created but I can see session key is getting created.
   [image]

Comment: i dont see any redis configuration or any sign of redis in this code. Vote too close, too little information. Good luck

Comment: Its standard redis configuration and nothing new or different

Comment: That information does not help, at all. Please update your question to containing a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue with the information provided. When I test with a Spring Initializr generated application with webflux+security+reactive redis+session and the above configuration no sessions are created. As @Toerktumlare mentions there is too little information in this question to determine your issue. Please provide dependencies, full configuration, and a request using cURL that reproduces the issue.